# Python reading from file into list then use line as list too and reach each char

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, io

I want to read a line from a file and make operation on specific char on that line.
I read line as in [link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python)

But there is a problem for me because I want to reach every single char in that file. My code is:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\BerkayS\Desktop\testfile.txt') as inputFile:
    content = inputFile.read().splitlines()
kelime = content[0:1]
```

here kelime is a list as expected. But it is a line in file actually, so I want to reach every char in that line, when I write

```
harf = kelime[2:5]
```

it returns empty because kelime's length is 1 as a whole string. How can I  split all chars and spaces in kelime into a new list that I can manupulate all of them?

Comment: `kelime = list(a_row) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kelime` is a one-element `list` where the sole element is a `str` containing the first line. But you're manipulating it as if you expect it to be a `str` (or a `list` of the individual characters).

If you want a `str`, use:

```
kelime = content[0]  # As opposed to content[0:1]
```

to index, not slice. If you want a `list` of the characters, do:

```
kelime = list(content[0])
```

to make a mutable `list` of the first line's characters.

Answer (score 1):

each `kelime` it's a list. you should do:

```
harf = kelime[0][2:5]
```